# MongoID has_any_belongs_to_many Reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have two models

Developer

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :founding_organizations, class_name: 'Organization'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborating_organizations, class_name: 'Organization'
```

Organization

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :founders, class_name: 'Developer'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, class_name: 'Developer'
```

How can I make the Developer model code work without changing anything on the organization model. Right now when you create an organization and use `organization.founders << current_developer` everything works fine and the developers id is stored in a founders array on the organization but if you query `current_developer.founding_organizations` the response is empty, how can I achieve this workflow? I had this working in ActiveRecord with joining tables but I moved to MongoDB which has so far been 10x better, its just getting used to doing things differently that has me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is possible without changing `Organization` model.
How about using `inverse_of` option?

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :founding_organizations, class_name: 'Organization', inverse_of: :founders
 has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborating_organizations, class_name: 'Organization', inverse_of: :collaborators

 has_and_belongs_to_many :founders, class_name: 'Developer', inverse_of: :founding_organizations
 has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, class_name: 'Developer', inverse_of: :collaborating_organizations
```

You'll find more info here http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common

Comment: Thanks for this, I put this in my app and everything seems to pass error checks but when I call current_developer.founding_organizations I still get nothing and after looking at the database manually I can see the organization itself has a list if founder id's but the developer itself has nothing in it that would tie it to an organization. Do I need to do anything else to accomplish this?

Comment: I just tried it in a sample app and it works for me as it is. Do you have any other relations in that models that may interfere? I suspect this or validation problems in `current_developer` object.

Comment: Apparently you need to call current_developer.founder_of << organization.founders instead of the opposite which I was using. Thanks for your help.